# How does the ShopifySharp Webhook.Address property get mapped to the callbackUrl property of the WebhookSubscription?

Tags: c#, webhooks, shopifysharp

I have a sample Shopify App developed which successfully subscribes to products/update webhook with help from the ShopifySharp library.  I am able to receive and process product update events successfully as well.

When I dig into the ShopifySharp source code (https://github.com/nozzlegear/ShopifySharp/blob/master/ShopifySharp/Entities/Webhook.cs) and compare with Shopify's documentation (https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/reference/events/webhooksubscription?api%5Bversion%5D=2021-01#fields-2020-04), Shopify's WebhookSubscription object does **not** have a property called Address.  It actually has a field called, "endpoint".

So, everything works, but I can't find the "secret sauce" that makes this happen.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking in the wrong place.  I should have been looking at the REST API reference instead of the GraphQL reference:

https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/events/webhook#index-2021-01

The REST API does use the property "address".